# nth-child css selector not working correctly if we had <br> tag in sibling of children elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, queryselector

a simple `<div>` with 5 `<span>` as children that end of any `<span>` i have `<br>` tag too.
when i want to select by `:nth-child(x)` any span element with index of more than 1 it's not worked
even selecting by `document.querySelector()` not worked
i test it on FireFox and Chrome too
when i removed `<br>` tags it's worked

how it's possible ?

```js
console.log("i have 5 span children as well : ", document.querySelectorAll(".div1>span").length);

console.log("second span child is null : ", document.querySelector(".div1>span:nth-child(2)"));

console.log("third span child is second span element : ", document.querySelector(".div1>span:nth-child(3)").textContent);

console.log("select second element by another way: ", document.querySelectorAll(".div1>span")[1].textContent);

console.log("tag name of second child: ", document.querySelector(".div1>*:nth-child(2)").tagName);
```

```css
html>body>div.div1>span:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="div1">
    <span>this is example text 1</span>
    <br>
    <span>this is example text 2</span>
    <br>
    <span>this is example text 3</span>
    <br>
    <span>this is example text 4</span>
    <br>
    <span>this is example text 5</span>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `:nth-child`, I think you need [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The queries work as expected. When you run `.div1>span:nth-child(2)` you are requesting for a span element that is the second child of its parent, in this case div1. Second child of div1 is a `<br>` and therefore you get null.

As suggested by Hao Wu, you should use [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

`document.querySelector(".div1>span:nth-of-type(2)")`
This will search for the second `span` element that is a child of div1

```js
console.log("i have 5 span children as well : ", document.querySelectorAll(".div1>span").length);

console.log("second span child is null : ", document.querySelector(".div1>span:nth-of-type(2)"));

console.log("third span child is second span element : ", document.querySelector(".div1>span:nth-of-type(3)").textContent);

console.log("select second element by another way: ", document.querySelectorAll(".div1>span")[1].textContent);

console.log("tag name of second child: ", document.querySelector(".div1>*:nth-child(2)").tagName);
```

```css
html>body>div.div1>span:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="div1">
    <span>this is example text 1</span>
    <br>
    <span>this is example text 2</span>
    <br>
    <span>this is example text 3</span>
    <br>
    <span>this is example text 4</span>
    <br>
    <span>this is example text 5</span>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```